# Sum of series having binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^n {n+r\choose r} \frac{1}{2^{r}}= 2^{n}$

what i try

$$\binom{n}{n}+\binom{n+1}{1}\frac{1}{2}+\binom{n+2}{2}\frac{1}{2^2}+\binom{n+3}{3}\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots +\binom{n+n}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}$$

$$\binom{n}{n}+\binom{n+1}{n}\frac{1}{2}+\binom{n+2}{n}\frac{1}{2^2}+\binom{n+3}{n}\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots +\binom{n+n}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$(1+x)^n+(1+x)^{n+1}\frac{1}{2}+(1+x)^{n+2}\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots\cdots +(1+x)^{2n}\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

How do i solve ithelp me plesse

Comment: We have different conceptions of what "trying" is...

Comment: It's worth noting that the last two terms of the sums are always equal. For example, when $n=4$ we get $$1+4+\frac{15}{4}+\frac{35}{8}+\frac{35}{8}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$S = \sum_{r=0}^n {n+r\choose r} \frac{1}{2^r}
= \sum_{r\ge 0} {n+r\choose n} \frac{1}{2^r}
[[0\le r\le n]]
\\ = \sum_{r\ge 0} {n+r\choose n} \frac{1}{2^r}
[z^n] \frac{z^r}{1-z}
= [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{r\ge 0} {n+r\choose n} \frac{1}{2^r} z^r
\\ = [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z/2)^{n+1}}
= 2^{n+1} [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(2-z)^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^n 2^{n+1} [z^n] \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}.$$

This is

$$(-1)^n 2^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{z-1} \frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}.$$

Resides sum to zero. The residue at infinity is zero by inspection.
The residue at $z=1$ is $- 2^{n+1}.$ For for the residue at $z=2$
we require

$$\frac{1}{n!} \left( \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{z-1} \right)^{(n)}
\\ = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}
(-1)^q \frac{(n+q)!}{n!} \frac{1}{z^{n+q+1}}
(-1)^{n-q} (n-q)! \frac{1}{(z-1)^{n-q+1}}
\\ = (-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^n {n+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{z^{n+q+1}}
\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n-q+1}}.$$

Evaluate at $z=2$ with the factor in front

$$(-1)^n 2^{n+1} (-1)^n
\sum_{q=0}^n {n+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{2^{n+q+1}}
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{2^{q}} = S.$$

This yields

$$S - 2^{n+1} + S = 0$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
S = 2^n.}$$

This      problem     is      a     special      case     of      [MSE
538309](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538309/).

**Addendum.**

An alternate approach uses

$$S = \sum_{q=0}^n {n+q\choose n} \frac{1}{2^q}
= \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{2^q} [z^n] (1+z)^{n+q}
= [z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{2^q} (1+z)^q
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n
\frac{1-(1+z)^{n+1}/2^{n+1}}{1-(1+z)/2}
= [z^n] (1+z)^n
\frac{2-(1+z)^{n+1}/2^{n}}{1-z}
\\ = 2\times 2^n
- [z^n] (1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = 2\times 2^n
- \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{q=0}^n {2n+1\choose q}
= 2\times 2^n - \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{2} 2^{2n+1}
= 2^n.$$