# simplification of combinatorial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Is there a simplified form of the following sum?

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n p^k{n+k\choose k}
$$

Comment: The value $p=1/2$ recently appeared at [MSE 3098562](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098562/).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to prove, by induction, that at $p = 1$, the series is equal to $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$.

At $p \neq 1$, [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bp%5Ek%20*%20Binomial%5Bn%2Bk,k%5D,%20%7Bk,%200,%20n%7D%5D), you can write this in terms of the hypergeometric function:
$$
\frac{1}{\left(1-p\right)^{n+1}}-{}_{2}F_{1}(1,2n+2,n+2;p)\binom{2n+1}{n+1}p^{n+1}.
$$
You should be able to prove the above with some patient algebra (you'll also need the definition of the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) when its third argument is equal to a positive integer).

**Note**: At $p = 0$, the expression above agrees with the series under the convention $0^0 = 1$, in which case both are equal to $1$.

That the expression is in terms of a special function should be a good indicator that outside of special cases (such as $p = 1$), you probably will not be able to find a "nice" closed form expression.

Comment: What ist $x$ in ${}_{2}F_{1}(1,2n+2,n+2;x)$?

Comment: +1 That was a typo. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Hypergeometric functions are just special ways to write series with certain ratios between terms:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\!\!\binom{n+k}{k}p^k
&=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}p^{n+1}\left[1+\frac{2n+2}{n+2}p+\frac{2n+2}{n+2}\frac{2n+3}{n+3}p^2+\cdots\right]\\
&=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}p^{n+1}{}_2F_1(1,2n+2;n+2;p)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
The first argument of $1$ cancels the $k!$ in $\frac{p^k}{k!}$.

The Binomial Theorem says
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\!\binom{n+k}{k}p^k
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-n-1}{k}p^k\\
&=(1-p)^{-n-1}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\!\binom{n+k}{k}p^k
=(1-p)^{-n-1}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}p^{n+1}{}_2F_1(1,2n+2;n+2;p)\tag3
$$