# For $x-y=z$, show $1=(-1)^{m+1}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{m+j}{j}\left(\frac{x^jy^{m+1}}{z^{m+j+1}}-(-1)^{m+j+1}\frac{x^{m+1}y^j}{z^{m+j+1}}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x-y=z$,
>   show that :
>   $$1=(-1)^{m+1}\sum_{j=0}^{m} \dbinom{m+j}{j}\left[\frac{x^jy^{m+1}}{z^{m+j+1}}-(-1)^{m+j+1}\frac{x^{m+1}y^j}{z^{m+j+1}}\right]$$

I tried expanding:
$$1=\left(\frac{x}{z}-\frac{y}{z}\right)^{m+1}$$ as it was given as a hint in the book but couldn't reach far enough ..

Comment: Have you looked at the [Binomial Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_formula)?

Comment: yes i know, but i can't find how that can lead to the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two sums (here $x-y=z$)

$$A = (-1)^{m+1} \frac{y^{m+1}}{z^{m+1}}
\sum_{j=0}^m {m+j\choose j} \frac{x^j}{z^j}$$

and

$$B = \frac{x^{m+1}}{z^{m+1}}
\sum_{j=0}^m {m+j\choose j} (-1)^j \frac{y^j}{z^j}$$

and we want to show that

$$A+B = 1.$$

Dividing by $z$ we find

$$\frac{x}{z}-\frac{y}{z} = 1.$$

We may put $x/z = p$ and $-y/z = 1-p.$ We get for $A$ and $B$

$$A = (1-p)^{m+1}
\sum_{j=0}^m {m+j\choose j} p^j$$

and

$$B = p^{m+1}   
\sum_{j=0}^m {m+j\choose j} (1-p)^j.$$

This is now revealed to be an instance of an identity by Gosper, which
appeared                 at                  this                 [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538309/).

Answer (score 1):

For $x=2,y=1,z=1\ and\ m=1$, we have:
$$RHS = (-1)^2 \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{2} \dbinom{j+1}{j} \left[x^j - (-1)^{j+2}x^2 \right] $$
$$= \sum_{j=0}^{2}(j+1)\left[2^j - (-1)^j\cdot4\right]$$
$$= 1\cdot (1-4)\ +\ 2\cdot(2+4)\ +\ 3\cdot(4-4)$$
$$=9$$
Therefore I think this is not true.